# Java - get value in field?

Tags: java

I dont know how to put this, but im trying to get the value of a value in a field. Here are some of the code (dont ask why i have length and height):

```
//person class
public person(double w, double h, double l){
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.length = l;
    }

//age class (extends person)
    public age(double w, double h, double l, int a) {
        super(w, h, l);
        this.age = a;
    }

//Creating the objects and putting them in an array (in the main class):
public person steve = new age(36.64, 185.64, 44.4, 26);
public person paul = new age(45.64, 178.64, 53.4, 47);

person[] people = new person[2];
people[0] = steve;
people[1] = paul;
```

Now i need to get the age of the people in the array. How would you do that?

Comment: Why do you create person with age constructor?

Comment: where is your age class ? Seems like it extends person, it has getters, setters ? Post the code for it

Comment: *FYI:* [Java Naming Conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201611272151346697502) are for class names to start with uppercase letter, i.e. `Person` and `Age`.

Comment: You're trying to do what now?

Comment: So `age` extends `person`? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You can *cast* `Person` to `Age`, e.g. `((Age) people[0]).getAge()`, but it's highly discouraged. You can add abstract `getAge()` method to `Person` and implement it in `Age`. Or you can stick to the `Age` class, instead of using the `Person` base class.

Comment: @Bubletan But you think a `person` class with `width`, `height`, and `length` fields makes sense? OP said *"dont ask why i have length and height"*, so read that as "don't ask about weird names, since no names here will make sense".

Comment: Problem is i also have another class with gender, which i forgot to include. sorry, that would've made this much clearer. Simply put theres also a person in the person[] with gender instead of age (works like age, extends person ect)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you understand :)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person pixelGrid = new Person();
    pixelGrid.setName("Pixel Grid");
    pixelGrid.setAge(18);
    System.out.println(pixelGrid);
  }
}

class Person {
   protected String sName;
   protected int sAge;

   public void setName(String sName) {
      this.sName = sName;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return sName;
   }

   public void setAge(int sAge) {
      this.sAge = sAge;
   }

   public int getAge() {
      return sAge;
   }

   public String toString() {
      String s = "The Persons Name is: " + getName() + "\n"; 
      s += "Their Age is: " + getAge() + "\n";
      return s;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
The Person's Name is: Pixel Grid
Their Age is: 18
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/E8qt/0)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the age directly from the arrays:

Some minor code change to the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        age steve = new age(36.64, 185.64, 44.4, 26);
        age paul = new age(45.64, 178.64, 53.4, 47);
        age[] people = new age[2];
        people[0] = steve;
        people[1] = paul;

        System.out.println(people[0].age);
        System.out.println(people[1].age);
}
```

Comment: must state thought, it is recommended to use getters and setters for retrieve instance variables - as per shash678 suggestion below